# Dynamic Conditional Correlation - insignificant correlation parameters

Tags: correlation, stata, garch

I am trying to get the variance covariance among 4 sectors using DCC in Stata.

```
mgarch dcc (var1, var2, var3, var4=), arch(1/1) garch(1/1)
```

The arch and garch parameters are significant but the p value of correlations is insignificant. What can be the reason and is it necessary for the correlations to be significant? The AIC is -447 and BIC is -367. When I apply garch(1/2) or garch(2/2), arch, garch and correlation parameters turn insignificant though AIC and BIC values are lower.

Comment: Can you add the estimation output? Have you tried to estimate a CCC-GARCH model?

Comment: @JohanStaxJakobsen i was told to fit the model using garch(1,2) garch(2,1) garch(2,2) etc and then keep checking for white noise using LM test. Stata doesnt allow for LM test after estimating dcc model. Instead can I go with Portmanteau or Bartlett test?